# Refactoring to no block parameters in a Ruby internal DSL

Tags: ruby, codeblocks, dsl, yield

I've got a little DSL that looks like this:

```
ActivityLogger.log do
  activity('27-06-2012') do
    eat do |act|
     act.duration = 15
     act.priority = 5
    end
  end
end
```

I want to refactor it so it loses the block params in the innermost block, so it looks like this:

```
ActivityLogger.log do
  activity('27-06-2012') do
    eat do
     duration = 15
     priority = 5
    end
  end
end
```

The `#eat` method instantiates a Log object:

```
def eat(&block)
  @logs << Log.new(Eat, &block)
end
```

Log's constructor yields `self` in the last line:

```
def initialize(activity, &block)
  @activity = activity
  yield self
end
```

To my mind, that is where the problem is. I've tried both using `instance_eval` in the `#eat` method (see link#2 below) and removing the `yield` statement from the Log's constructor entirely (link#3), but none of these approaches work (the Log object gets created, but doesn't get its `#duration` and `#priority` methods set).

Here are the links:

1) [A working DSL with block parameters](https://gist.github.com/3010757)

2) [Non-working DSL, first refactoring attempt](https://gist.github.com/3010768)

3) [Non-working DSL, second refactoring attempt](https://gist.github.com/3010784)

Thanks!

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851127/change-the-context-binding-inside-a-block-in-ruby and article http://www.dan-manges.com/blog/ruby-dsls-instance-eval-with-delegation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`duration = 15` doesn't call the setter method as you expect but defines a local variable `duration`. You have to either call the setter explicitly via `self.duration = 15` or implement your setter like

```
def duration(value)
  @duration = value
end
```

and call `duration 15`.

Comment: When I use `duration = 15` with block params it does set the value as expected. These methods are declared as `attr_accessor` in the Log class, and the values can be seen by inspecting them as I do in the `ActivityLogger#report` method.

Comment: You call `act.duration = 15`, not just `duration = 15`

Comment: Yes. When I call `duration = 15` nothing happens - which is the point of this thread.

Comment: This is because `duration = 15` defines a variable, just like `i = 1`

Comment: @user906230: Stefan is right, when writing DSLs you either use `something.xyz = 1` or `xyz 1`. `xyz = 1` will *always* create a local variables, that's how scoping in Ruby works.

Comment: I understand but this isn't the point of the question. I am calling `something.xyz = 1` now, so no local variables are created.

Comment: Solved: got rid of `yield self` in the Log constructor, am using `xyz = 1` in the calls with explicit setters as Stefan suggested. Thanks for the comments.