# How can I use a block to change the execution context in ruby?

Tags: ruby, block

I'm creating a `factory` for an account object and I'm setting the name like this:

```
name { "#{Faker::Hacker.ingverb} #{Faker::Hacker.adjective} #{Faker::Hacker.noun}" }
```

Is there a way to use a block to change the execution context to eliminate the redundant `Faker::Hacker` calls? I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
name { Faker::Hacker { "#{ingverb} #{adjective} #{noun}" } }
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5851127/438992 Nutshell: `binding` is your friend--if it's really worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are sending methods to a class/module, so your example may be simply rewritten with use of [Module#class_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) method:

`name { Faker::Hacker.class_eval { "#{ingverb} #{adjective} #{noun}" } }`

would invoke methods in the block passed to `class_eval` on `Faker::Hacker` class.

Answer (score 0):

Not a total solution according to your problem, but a lot less to type:

```
h = Faker::Hacker
name { "#{h.ingverb} #{h.adjective} #{h.noun}" }
```