# Ruby exercise - block to array

Tags: ruby

I'm playing Ruby game and got stuck at this :

> Implement class `Squirrel` in a way below API will be supported.
>
> ```
> squirrel = Squirrel.new
> squirrel.fight do
>   jump
>   kick
>   punch
>   jump
> end
>
> squirrel.actions #=> ['jump', 'kick', 'punch', 'jump']
> ```

I was experimenting with `def find(&block)` and saving it as Proc later, but it probably shouldn't be done this way. I'll appreciate any hints.

Comment: The exercise doesn't contain a method called `find`, why do you want to define it?

Comment: @Stefan: I think he meant `fight`

Answer (score 2):

> I'll appreciate any hints

Sure. `fight` should accept a block and `instance_eval` it. `jump`, `kick` and others should be methods on the same class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather standard metaprogramming technique that was popularized many years ago by the [`BlankSlate`](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder/blob/master/lib/blankslate.rb#L35-L74) and [`XmlBase`](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder/blob/master/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb#L88-L94) classes in [Jim Weirich](https://Wikipedia.org/Jim_Weirich)'s [`builder`](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder) Gem.

The main idea is to create a "blank slate" object, i.e. an object that has no methods, and then record all method calls on this object.

Here is one possible implementation:

```
class Squirrel
  class Recorder < BasicObject
    (instance_methods + private_instance_methods).each(&method(:undef_method))
    def method_missing(method) @actions << method.to_s end
  end

  attr_reader :actions, :recorder

  private
  attr_writer :actions, :recorder

  def initialize
    self.actions = []
    self.recorder = Recorder.allocate
    Object.public_instance_method(:instance_variable_set).bind(recorder).(:@actions, actions)
  end

  public def fight(&block)
    BasicObject.public_instance_method(:instance_eval).bind(recorder).(&block)
  end
end

require 'minitest/autorun'
describe Squirrel do
  before do @squirrel = Squirrel.new end

  describe '#fight' do
    it 'should record its actions' do
      @squirrel.fight do              jump; kick; punch; jump end
      @squirrel.actions.must_equal %w[jump  kick  punch  jump]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `instance_eval`. And/or read this this:
[Change the context/binding inside a block in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851127/change-the-context-binding-inside-a-block-in-ruby)

Comment: He didn't ask for a full solution. Just hints. You're taking all the fun away :)